# Flutter stateful widget

Tags: flutter, widget

```
class AppWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 _AppWidgetState createState() => _AppWidgetState();
}


class _AppWidgetState extends State<AppWidget> {

  int _Count = 0;

  build(context){}
}
```

I'm familiar with stateless and stateful widget in flutter but I'm curious why we're not defining stateful widget same as stateless widget? Why we need to declare 2 different class one for **createstate method** and one for actual state implementation?

I guess may be flutter team use this implementation because when app re-run we can get old state back without losing it if this is the case then How flutter knows?

And if application have more then 1 stateful widget then how flutter manage state for each stateful widget? Again my guess is flutter manage state based on `State<AppWidget>` but again HOW?

Comment: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkyY9WCGMi0

Answer (score 0):

First class is the one that rebuilds the widget if you change anything in it. So for example if you have a text widget in the stateful widget and in the runtime you pressed a button and changed the text from 'Hello World' to 'Hello User' actually what happens is that flutter destroys the second class and rebuild it again with the new text using the first one.

You can find more information in this video from the Flutter Team:
[Stateful Widgets Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AqCMFXEmf3w)